# Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring'] not found error when defining plugin in .gradle.kts files under buildSrc directory

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am trying to create plugins for a multi-module Kotlin application such as build configurations can be more easily maintained shared among several modules (core, model, lib, app) using Gradle 6.8.1.

At the root project directory, `gradle init` is executed and the following options are inputted.

| option | selection |
| --- | --- |
| type | application |
| language | Kotlin |
| multiple subprojects | yes |
| build script DSL | Kotlin |

The following `.gradle.kts` files are generated under `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin` directory.

- my.package.kotlin-applications.gradle.kts
- my.package.kotlin-common-conventions.gradle.kts
- my.package.kotlin-library-conventions.gradle.kts

As I will be using Spring Boot features, I am trying to add several plugins in `my.package.kotlin-library-conventions.gradle.kts` which will be used by lib and app modules.

```
plugins {
    id("my.package.kotlin-common-conventions")

    // new plugins
    kotlin("plugin.spring")
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")

    `java-library`
}
```

When I execute `gradle build`, the following error is returned.

```
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

I tried to edit the contents in below files but still cannot resolve the above error.

**settings.gradle.kts**

```
pluginManagement {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
        maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
    }

    plugins {
        kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21-2"
        kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.21-2"
        id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.0-SNAPSHOT"
        id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    }
}
```

**buildSrc/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`

    kotlin("plugin.spring")
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()

    jcenter()
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
}
```